# Do office workers like public transport?

Tags: cities-skylines

My city is quite large now and I'm working to try and cut my traffic by investing in public transport. However the game doesn't tell me specifically the types of passengers using my transport. I'm not keen to go and find all my passengers personally and click them to find out their status.

So should I be placing bus stops and metro stops near to offices, schools and other public and service buildings? Or is the effect of a transport stop/station literally just to improve the happiness of folk in the area of the stop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Citizens will always look for the fastest way to get to their destination. They will either use a car, or combine different kinds of public transportation with going on foot, whichever appears to be faster. You can make your citizens a bit more biased to using public transportation instead of cars by enabling the "Free Public Transportation" policy.

This means that when you want to reduce traffic, you should place stops near buildings which receive many visitors. Educational buildings are a prime candidate for this, as well as any parks and unique buildings. But you should also make sure that no residential buildings are too far away from the nearest station.

A good strategy is usually to use a subways network to connect different parts of your city and then use bus lines to connect each subway station to nearby buildings.

Comment: "Citizens will always look for the fastest way to get to their destination." You've somewhat contradicted this yourself by mentioning the "Free Public Transportation" policy. Citizens don't always look for the fastest way; they take travel cost into account too (based on how well off they are, they are open to faster but more expensive routes). Car travel cost is linear (per distance travelled),whereas public transportation is more expensive for short trips; but starts being cheaper as the travel distance increases. Pedestrians and cyclists travel without cost, but they are by far the slowest.

Comment: Note that the travel costs are not mentioned ad verbatim in the game, but they do exist. All you can do is increase/decrease the public transportation cost to change the citizens' preference towards public transportation. Also, as a slightly more direct answer to OP's question, office workers tend to be above average (financially speaking), which means they are more likely to take public transportation for short distances (which is a bit more expensive than travelling by car), so you should see a slightly higher usage of public transportation by office workers.